# Sorting a list in specific order using substrings

Tags: python

I have a list of some strings that looks like this:

`my_list = ['0123_abcd', '1234_bcde', '2345_cdef', '3456_defg', '4567_efgh']`

I want to sort this list by using another list containing only substrings of the first list:

`ordering = ['3456', '2345', '0123']`

Every Element which is in `my_list` but not in `ordering` shall be set to the end of the list. So my expected result would be:

`result_list = ['3456_defg', '2345_cdef', '0123_abcd', '1234_bcde', '4567_efgh']`

My code so far:

`result_list = sorted(my_list, key=lambda e: (ordering.index(e),e) if e in ordering  else (len(ordering),e))`

This works fine, as long as my_list looks like this: `my_list = ['0123', '1234', '2345', '3456', '4567']`. If I add the underscore and some letters after the numbers in `my_list` it does not work. I don't get any error message but the ordering is wrong.

So I would guess I have to use something like `.split('_')[0]` somewhere in my line of code. But

`result_list = sorted(my_list, key=lambda e: e.split("_")[0] (ordering.index(e),e) if e in ordering  else (len(ordering),e))`
also does not work.

How do I get this list sorting right?

Comment: are the strings in `ordering` always formed by 4 chars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the strings in `ordering` are unique, then this is a possible solution:

```
ordering_dict = {s: i for i, s in enumerate(ordering)}
sorted_list = sorted(
    my_list,
    key=lambda x: ordering_dict.get(x.split("_")[0], len(ordering_dict)),
)
```

This has the advantage over other methods to not have quadratic complexity!

Answer (score 2):

I think you can make a sorting function that returns the index of the key from `my_list` in `ordering` or a max value.

```py
my_list = ['0123_abcd', '1234_bcde', '2345_cdef', '3456_defg', '4567_efgh']
ordering = ['3456', '2345', '0123']

def fn_sort(item):
    try:
        index = ordering.index(item.split("_")[0])
    except ValueError:
        index = len(ordering)
    return index

print(sorted(my_list, key=fn_sort))
```

I might build a closure to pre-calculate the max index. Perhaps like:

```py
def build_sorter(ordering):
    max_index = len(ordering)
    def fn_sort(item):
        try:
            return ordering.index(item.split("_")[0])
        except ValueError:
            return max_index
    return fn_sort

my_list = ['0123_abcd', '1234_bcde', '2345_cdef', '3456_defg', '4567_efgh']
ordering = ['3456', '2345', '0123']
print(sorted(my_list, key=build_sorter(ordering)))
```

That should give you:

```
['3456_defg', '2345_cdef', '0123_abcd', '1234_bcde', '4567_efgh']
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to define the sort key function by iterating over the ordering list and returning the index if the substring is present in the current word. If no entry is a substring, return a number that is larger than all the indices.

```py
def order_index(word):
    for i, s in enumerate(ordering):
        if s in word:
            return i
    return len(ordering)


my_list.sort(key=order_index)
print(my_list)
```

```
['3456_defg', '2345_cdef', '0123_abcd', '1234_bcde', '4567_efgh']
```